# How to gF (go to file Particular line) to popup window?

Tags: neovim, vim8, popup-menu

In vim8 there is a popup window feature which seems like vscode peek definition. Often I use `gF` to go to file with particular line number. Is there a way to open a file in popup window?

Comment: Not what you want, but try this: `:set pvp=height:10,width:60 | nno <key> :<c-u>pedit <c-r><c-p><cr>`.  Replace `<key>` with whatever key sequence you want.  See [`:h preview-popup`](https://vimhelp.org/windows.txt.html#preview-popup) and [`:h c^r^p`](https://vimhelp.org/cmdline.txt.html#c_CTRL-R_CTRL-P).

Comment: @user938271 to me that seems exactly what OP wants (didn't specify the ability to edit it..)

Comment: But it doesn't handle the line number; although, I guess it wouldn't be too difficult to support with a bit of Vim script.

Answer (score 3):

You can use any of the `popup_*` functions that open popups with a buffer number, so,

```
let bufnr = bufadd(expand('<cfile>'))
let popup_id = popup_create (bufnr, {})
```